# Dash tutoriel error : Unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

i'm learning Dash following this tutoriel https://github.com/amyoshino/Dash_Tutorial_Series
the problem is that when i install the project and try to run app.py function i found this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 58, in <module>
   dcc.Checklist(
 File 
 "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
 LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\dash\development\base_component.py", 
 line 42, in wrapper
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File 
 "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\
  local-packages\Python38\site-packages\dash_core_components\Checklist.py", line 69, in __init__
   super(Checklist, self).__init__(**args)
  File 

 "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
 LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\dash\development\base_component.py", line 82, in 
 __init__
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `values`
Allowed arguments: className, id, inputClassName, inputStyle, labelClassName, labelStyle, 
loading_state, options, persisted_props, persistence, persistence_type, style, value
```

PS: I have installed all the requirements and libraries needed

when i change values with value the code runs but when i open the localhost another error occur

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2021 15:53:20] "←[35m←[1mGET /_dash-component- 
suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.min.js.map?v=1.8.3 HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 File 
 "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File 
  "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
   PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
     packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in 
    handle_exception
   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
   PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
   packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
   raise value
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
   PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
  packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
  PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
  packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in 
  full_dispatch_request
   rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in 
 handle_user_exception
 reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
 raise value
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in 
 full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
  PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
  packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in 
  dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File 
  "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
  PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-            
  packages\Python38\site-packages\
  dash\dash.py", line 393, in serve_component_suites
  mimetype = ({
  KeyError: 'map'
  127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2021 15:53:21] "←[35m←[1mGET /_dash-component-                                    
   suites/dash_renderer/dash_renderer.min.js.map?v=1.8.3 
  HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File                 "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-     
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-          
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
   File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\
 Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-     
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in 
 handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File 
"C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\
Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in 
 full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in 
handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in 
 full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in 
 dispatch_request
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\
 PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local- 
 packages\Python38\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 393, in 
 serve_component_suites
mimetype = ({
KeyError: 'map'
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2021 15:53:21] "←[37mGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

Comment: As pointed out in @coralvanda's answer, there is more than one, so I'll let you know. line52,line106,line136

Answer (score 1):

That repo contains the error. As the traceback informs you, `values` is not allowed there, but you can use `value`. Change it locally and it should resolve the error. Additionally, you could make a pull request to that repo and help the original author(s) by fixing a bug in their code.

Comment: it runs now but when i open localhost the dashboard does not appear and another error occure 
i'll add it now in the question